# Create a mySQL table with a varying number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables, say `user` and `apparel`.

I want to build a third table called `order`.

User table is having `user Id, Name,Email.` etc columns.

Apparel table is having `Apparel Id, Description, Price`.etc

Third table will contain `user order info. Order(User Id, ApparelID1, ApparelID2.` etc).

A user can order any number of items.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this third table which will store all orders of a single user.

Comment: So is it about MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Don't store all orders in one line. Have a table with orderid-userid pairs. You can select orders by user easily then, without any additional design problems.

Comment: There's a tutorial for database beginners:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/ it contains three parts

Answer (score 3):

Why not just have:  `Order(Order Id(PK), User Id(FK), Apparel Id(FK), Order Number)`?

```
1, 1, 1, 'Order1'
2, 1, 2, 'Order1'
3, 2, 1, 'Order2'
```

Order Number is NOT UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

In Order table only
User Id, ApparelId

And multiple rows per user

Answer (score 0):

Well I can suggest a solution to your problem, You can implement if you like.

Let the Order table have columns (UserId, ApparellId, OrderId), So when the user orders multiple Apparell in a single transaction, let it be stored in the table as multiple rows with each Appararel Id and all of them having the same Order Id.

Answer (score 0):

**Order(OrderId int, UserId int, ApparelId int)**

Make `OrderId` , `UserId` , `ApparelId` as **Primary Key** in their respective tables.